# what does 0 as output means in AverageAbsoluteDifferenceRecommenderEvaluator in mahout?

Tags: mahout, recommendation-engine, mahout-recommender

I am currently playing with Apache mahout and reading book Mahout in Action and it confused me about the evaluator which we use in evaluation of  recommender system and specifically i wanted to ask about `AverageAbsoluteDifferenceRecommenderEvaluator` i.e when it results in `0`.

Does it means there is no error or does it means recommendation system is very bad?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

0 means a perfect match.

RecommenderEvaluator returns MeanAverageError, representing how well the Recommender's estimated preferences match real values; lower scores mean a better match: 0 no error at all.

[more](http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh4/cdh/4/mahout-0.7-cdh4.3.2/mahout-core/org/apache/mahout/cf/taste/eval/RecommenderEvaluator.html#evaluate%28org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.eval.RecommenderBuilder,%20org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.eval.DataModelBuilder,%20org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.model.DataModel,%20double,%20double%29)